# dbGetQuery does not recognise user as database in command but as some systematic variable

Tags: sql, r, postgresql

I am trying to connect to the database in R using PostgreSQL. However, I have issues with quotation marks for database user - sql see user as some kind of systematic variable. Thus in the standard sql interface I would use

```
select count(*), email, name
from http_request_log hrl
inner join user_access_token uat on hrl.access_token_id = uat.id and uat.impersonated_by_id is null
inner join "user" u on uat.user_id = u.id
inner join customer c on u.customer_id = c.id
where hrl.created_time >= '2020-05-01'
group by u.email, c.name
order by count(*) desc
```

But in R, using dbGetQuery, there is an issue with quotation marks - I cannot use "user" and if I change to ' it does not work - it only works if the whole command starts and end with ' instead " - but then the where clause is not working as it does not recognize the date

```
uzivatele <- dbGetQuery(con, 
                        "select count(*), email, name
                        from http_request_log hrl
                        inner join user_access_token uat on hrl.access_token_id = uat.id and uat.impersonated_by_id is null
                        inner join 'user' u on uat.user_id = u.id
                        inner join customer c on u.customer_id = c.id
                        where hrl.created_time >= '2020-05-01'
                        group by u.email, c.name
                        order by count(*) desc")
```

Comment: Why can't use use `"user"` (double-quotes) instead of `'user'` (single-quotes) in R? You can also create the string with `'select count(*), ... inner join "user" u on ...'` (notice the single-quotes on the outside, doubles on the inside.)

Answer (score 0):

`user` is a reserved word in PostgreSQL.

One way to get around this is to prefix the table name with the schema name, e.g. `public.user` in your query.

Or you could try `\"user\"` in your [query string](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html#:%7E:text=Single%20quotes%20need%20to%20be,quotes%20in%20double%2Dquoted%20strings.&text=Alternative%20forms%20for%20the%20last,strings%20by%20scan%20and%20read.).